# Correctly configure Bitbucket Pipelines to continuously deploy Nuxtjs static-site folder to Firebase hosting folder

Tags: git, firebase, nuxt.js, bitbucket-pipelines, static-site

I want to continuously deploy my static site folder on Firebase using Bitbucket pipelines.

All the files relating to development are stored and version-controlled in Bitbucket and as it is a Nuxt site, the public folder to be deployed to Firebase is called `dist`.

I've coded a few test pages, have git watch for any changes and then create new versions of the static pages in the `dist` folder using the command:

`npm run generate`

Once all changes are committed, everything is pushed to the Bitbucket repo.

Using the firebase CLI, I deploy new pushes that change the contents of the `dist` folder to Firebase using the Firebase CLI command:

`firebase deploy --only hosting --token "$FIREBASE_TOKEN" --public dist`.

Now I want to make it continuous deployment so that every time I make a commit and then push it would deploy automatically to firebase.

I have looked through all the tutorials people have created and other stack questions but cannot seem to get it to work. Currently, my pushed commits trigger the pipeline which then seems to run the firebase deploy command,  but the site does not change. If I then go to the Firebase CLI and run the deploy command, it works immediately.

No errors show, and before you ask, I have created the tokens in the environment for Firebase login.

**Perhaps my understanding as to what a pipeline is and how it works is fundamentally flawed, so maybe someone could clear it up for me?**

I assumed that if I generate the dist folder before I push it to Bitbucket, I would simply need to install and run firebase tools and then can deploy to Firebase the already created `dist` folder. I was applying this method as it saves on the pipeline times to completion but perhaps I have to make the pipeline re-run `generate` and then `deploy`?

Below are the copies of my package.json, firebase.json and bitbucket-pipelines.yml file and the contents:

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "first-site",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "nuxt.js project",
  "author": "pf",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue --ignore-path .gitignore .",
    "precommit": "npm run lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "nuxt": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.1",
    "eslint": "^4.15.0",
    "eslint-friendly-formatter": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^4.0.0"
  }
}
```

**firebase.json:**

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      ".nojekyll",
      "**/.firebase/**",
      "**/.nuxt/**",
      "**/assets/**",
      "**/components/**",
      "**/layouts/**",
      "**/middleware/**",
      "**/node_modules/**",
      "**/pages/**",
      "**/plugins/**",
      "**/static/**",
      "**/store/**",
      ".editorconfig",
      ".eslintrc.js",
      ".firebaserc",
      ".gitignore",
      "bitbucket-pipelines.yml",
      "locations.net",
      "nuxt.config.js",
      "package-lock.json",
      "package.json"
    ]
  }
}
```

**bitbucket-pipelines.yml:**

```
image: node:6.9.4

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
          - node
        script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
    - echo "working on master branch."
      - apk update
      - export FIREBASE_PROJECT=$FIREBASE_PROJECT
      - export FIREBASE_TOKEN=$FIREBASE_TOKEN
      - npm install -g firebase-tools
      - firebase use ${FIREBASE_PROJECT} --token ${FIREBASE_TOKEN}
      - firebase deploy --only hosting --token "$FIREBASE_TOKEN" --public dist
      - echo "Everything is awesome!"
```